# Can a single Java thread take down entire JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

If a Java process hangs (due to bug in JNI (faces deadlock), Can it result in blocking of entire JVM? i.e. all processes and threads getting blocked?

Comment: Why is this question not closed on the grounds of being "too broad" ?

Comment: What do you mean with “all processes”? A JVM is only one process.

Comment: @Holger Sorry for the terminology what I meant was all the threads related to the process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*due to bug in JNI* **Yes**. If you call into native code a bug can easily bring down the entire JVM (or block everything).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you provide any resource that can help me in further analysis or any official docs that describes this issue.

Comment: [IBM developerWorks Best practices for using the Java Native Interface Techniques and tools for averting the 10 most common JNI programming mistakes](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jni/) says (in part) *Using JNI within your application provides powerful low-level access to the machine resources (memory, I/O, and so on), so you're working without the safety net usually provided to Java developers. JNI's flexibility and power introduce the risk of programming practices that can lead to poor performance, bugs, and even program crashes*

Answer (score 0):

No.  The thread or threads in deadlock will remain blocked, but other threads can run independently in other programs or even in the same program.  Obviously deadlocks should be avoided whenever possible, but the affected threads will only be the threads in deadlock and any and all threads waiting on the completion of those threads.

Answer (score 0):

Normally every application has it's own JVM instance running. So you could not crash other applications by trying to crash your current JVM . However some application share one JVM like a Web server for instance.

Another scenario would be if it crashes anything on an operating system level. Well then everything related to that will shut down.